# How to get values from multiple Textareas in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I have a form that has more than 1 `textarea`(3 to exact). The issue is that, if I type something in 1 `textarea` then the other `textareas` are also filled and updated. And I dont' want that. I'm using an `onChange` handler to make them controlled components but they're not behaving as expected. I've looked online but couldn't find a solution! How do I make them update individually on change/type?

#### React Textarea component

```
const Textarea = ({ labelText, placeholder, value, name, onChange }) => {
  return (
    <div className="textarea-panel">
      <label>{labelText}</label>
      <textarea
        style={{ display: 'block' }}
        cols="60"
        rows="5"
        placeholder={placeholder}
        value={value}
        name={name}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Textarea;
```

#### React Form component

```
import Textbox from './Textbox';

export class Form extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: {
        career: '',
        experience: '',
        additionalInformation: '',
      },
    };

    this.handleTextareaChange = this.handleTextareaChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleTextareaChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      data: {
        [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
      },
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Textbox
              labelText="Write your career "
              value={this.state.data.career}
              placeholder="e.g. extra information"
              name="career"
              onChange={this.handleTextareaChange}
            />
            <span>{this.state.data.career}</span>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Textbox
              labelText="Write your experience"
              value={this.state.data.experience}
              placeholder="e.g. extra information"
              name="experience"
              onChange={this.handleTextareaChange}
            />
            <span>{this.state.data.experience}</span>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Textbox
              labelText="Additional information"
              value={this.state.data.additionalInformation}
              placeholder="e.g. extra information"
              name="additionalInformation"
              onChange={this.handleTextareaChange}
            />
            <span>{this.state.data.additionalInformation}</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Form;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overriding the entire state with a new key on the data object. Every time the onChange handler is called the entire state gets overriden with a new data object with the current textbox's name as the key. Instead just update the particluar key on the data like this

Try it here : [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/1370702lz7)

```
handleTextareaChange(event) {
  const { data } = this.state
  data[event.target.name] = event.target.value
  this.setState({
    data
  });
}
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: His original code works fine, the bug is not there.

Comment: By the code it looks like he wants to have 3 pieces of state for each textbox like `{ data : { career:"", experience:"", additionalInformation:""} }`. But , only one piece of state is preserved at a time which does not make any sense. You can check my codesandbox.

Comment: @HemantParashar thanks, for solving this. That is exactly what I wanted! You have clearly define my issue in 1 word and solved it, many thanks!